# Python, probability

Tags: python, list, char, line, probability

My code is next:

```
with open("test.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1

list= [(count, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
```

This code open **test.txt**, read every line and "list" sign into form for example: **[(3, 'a'),.........]**. This means that in whole text file, there are three a and so on...

What I need is to calculate for this number, **instead 3**, I need **[ 3 / number of all sign ]**. So I don't need number of how many sign for example a is in text, but I need probability of sign a.

So if in text(test.txt) there will be **"aaab"**, I need output of "list": **[(0.75, 'a'), (0.25, 'b')]**

Many thanks for help.

---

**EDIT2**

```
import collections
frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)



with open("test.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1
total = float(sum(frequencies.keys()))

verj= [(count/total, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
```

This not working, give me error:

> ```
> total = float(sum(frequencies.keys()))
> ```
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I assume you're initializing `frequencies` to `0` values? Consider using [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: That should be `frequencies.values()` on the line in the edit, not `frequencies.keys()`. After all, it's the values of that dict where the number of occurrences is stored. (The keys store the character symbols.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `frequencies = {"a": 3, "b": 4}` then `frequencies.values()` gives us `[3, 4]` and we can calculate the sum:

```
total = float(sum(frequencies.values()))
```

and then the probabilities:

```
probs = [(count / total, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
```

Note that Python returns an integer when dividing two integers, which was the reason I converted the sum into a float first:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3 / 4
0
>>> 3 / 4.0
0.75
```

Comment: OK, I understand this, but python gives me an error:
    total = float(sum(frequencies.keys()))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Yes, because you are summing the **keys** (letters) instead of the **values** (counts). You can't add letters to letters :)

Comment: Please look at edit 2, can you fix this code so it will work?
Many thanks

Comment: Yes, just change the word 'keys' into 'values' as I've said about 3 times now :)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

```
with open("test.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1
total = float(sum(frequencies.values()))
symbols = [(count/total, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
```

Note that I've renamed your resulting list because `list` is the name of a built-in and you shouldn't use it to name variables or functions.

Comment: You need to sum the values, not the keys. Also if the numbers are integers then you'll need to apply `float()` to the total so the division produces a float.

Comment: total = sum(frequencies.keys())

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

--->error, not working

Comment: Exactly. Sum the values instead of the keys and, while you're at it, apply `float()` to the result of the sum otherwise all of your probabilities will round down to zero.

Comment: Can you please add answer "code", because I really don't know what you mean. thanks

Comment: I don't know where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I *did* type the wrong thing! @SimonJ: thanks for spotting that. @thanking: It's fixed now, use the updated version!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
   counter = 0
   with open("test.txt") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            for char in line:
                frequencies[char] += 1
                counter += 1

    list= [(count / counter, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
```

Comment: I don't know where is the problem?

Comment: Python has no `++` operator. Use `counter += 1` instead.